# how to convert sqlite3 datetime to 24 hrs

Tags: python, sqlite

I am parsing through a JSON file with a string of datetime like this:

```
"col_datetime": "10/18/2017 2:45:00 PM"
```

I am using python's datetime.strptime to make this a sqlite datetime:

```
datetime.strptime(col_datetime, '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S %p')
```

this is stored in the sqlite table like this:

```
2017-10-18 02:45:00.000000
```

But when I try to parse this using strftime in sqlite3 it seems not getting the PM

```
strftime('%H:%M',col_datetime)
```

This returns to:

> 2:45

Instead of:

> 14:45

Any thoughts on this?

Comment: If this is your actual format of the date it would give null as a result and not 2:55.

Comment: @forpas Ahh, yes ofcourse. Here is the actual datetime `2017-10-18 02:45:00.000000`

Comment: So is there AM or PM at the end?

Comment: @forpas Nope, it doesn't have it

Comment: The sqlite date and time functions expect hours to be in 24 hour format. So that should return `02:45`, not `2:55`. You're not getting a leading 0 and what's with the 55 instead of 45?

Comment: How do you store the date time? The fault does not seem to be in the retrieving method.

Comment: Edit your question and post the actual data and results you get.

Comment: if you execute `strftime('%H:%M',col_datetime)` for `2017-10-18 02:45:00.000000` you get `02:45`, so what is the problem?

Comment: @forpas I have edited it more, I apologize I have given the full context of what I have done

Comment: Can you explain why for this date: `2017-10-18 02:45:00.000000` you want `14:45` as a result?

Comment: @forpas I want to be the same as what the original time stamp was which is `2:45:00 PM`

Comment: How are you going from the object returned by `time.strptime()` (*Not* `datetime.strptime()`, at least on python 3.6), to the string being inserted into the database?

Comment: Also note that sqlite `strftime()` does not have any format options for 12-hour times, or AM/PM status, just 24. So you won't be able to do what you want with it alone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `%I` for 12 hour format in `strptime` instead of `%H`.

Here's an example where you can see it works as expected with that change:

```
>>> datetime.strptime('10/18/2017 2:45:00 PM', '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S %p')
datetime.datetime(2017, 10, 18, 2, 45)
>>> datetime.strptime('10/18/2017 2:45:00 PM', '%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p')
datetime.datetime(2017, 10, 18, 14, 45)
```

Comment: Okay this change is what I needed. Silly me.